# Is there a better, maybe more reliable pattern than "fire and forget" to handle variable number of asynchronous tasks concurrently?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have following code:

```cs
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var connection = await listener.AcceptAsync(cancellationToken);

    HandleConnectionAsync(connection, cancellationToken)
        .FireAndForget(HandleException);
}
```

The `FireAndForget` is an extension method:

```cs
public static async void FireAndForget(this ValueTask task, Action<Exception> exceptionHandler)
{
    try
    {
        await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exceptionHandler.Invoke(e);
    }
}
```

The `while loop` is the server lifecycle. When new connection is accepted then it starts some "background task" so it can handle this new connection and then `while loop` goes back to accepting new connections without awaiting anything - pausing the lifecycle.

I cannot `await` `HandleConnectionAsync` (pause the lifecycle) here, because I want to immediately accept another connection (if there is one) and be able to handle multiple connections concurrently. `HandleConnectionAsync` is I/O bound and handles one connection at time until closed (task completes after some time).

The connections have to be handled separately - I don't want to have a situation when some error while handling one connection have any influence on other connections.

The "fire and forget" solution I have here works, but the general rule is to always `await` asynchronous methods and never use `async void`.

It seems like I've broken the rules, so is there a better, maybe more reliable way to handle variable (number of tasks varies in time) number of asynchronous I/O bound tasks concurrently in a situation described here?

More information:

- Each call to `AcceptAsync` allocates system resources even before returning the connection and I want to avoid that whenever possible (the connection may not be returned for hours (code may "await" for hours) - until some external client decides to connect to my server). It is better to assume that this is the method I don't want to be called concurrently/in parallel - just one `AcceptAsync` at time is enough
- Please take into account that I can have millions of clients per day connecting and disconnecting to my server and server (`while loop`) can work for many many days
- I don't know how many connections I will need to handle at a specific time
- I do know the maximum number of connections my program will be able to handle concurrently
- If I hit the `maximum number of connections` limit then `AcceptAsync` won't return new connection until some other active connection closes, so I don't need to worry about that, but any solution based on this limit have to take into account that the active connections may be closed and I still need to handle new connections - number of connections varies over time. "fire and forget" have no issues with that
- The code for `HandleConnectionAsync` is not relevant - it just handles one connection at time until closed (task completes after some time) and is I/O bound (`HandleConnectionAsync` handles one connection at time, but of course we can start multiple `HandleConnectionAsync` tasks to handle multiple connections concurrently - which is what I did with "fire and forget")

Comment: `Task.WaitAll`?

Comment: @404 I think you meant `Task.WhenAll` - I'm not sure how to apply it here, because I don't have fixed collection of tasks. As I mentioned in "More information" section I don't know specific number of connections at specific time - it can be one, two or 1000 and it can vary in time

Comment: Well you could also bundle them with `Task.WhenAll`, but in the end if you don't want to fire and forgot you have to wait for their completion at some point. Whether that's with the bundled task or `Task.WaitAll`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that changing to something like SignalR isn't an acceptable solution. That would be my first recommendation.

Custom server sockets is a scenario where some kind of "fire and forget" is acceptable. I'm considering adding a "task manager" kind of type to AsyncEx to make this kind of solution easier, but haven't done it yet.

The bottom line is that you need to manage your list of connections yourself. The "connection" object can include a `Task` that represents the handling loop; that's fine. It's also useful (especially for debugging or management purposes) to have other properties on there as well, such as the remote IP.

So I would approach it something like this:

```
private readonly object _mutex = new object();
private readonly List<State> _connections = new List<State>();

private void Add(State state)
{
  lock (_mutex)
    _connections.Add(state);
}
private void Remove(State state)
{
  lock (_mutex)
    _connections.Remove(state);
}

public async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  while (true)
  {
    var connection = await listener.AcceptAsync(cancellationToken);

    Add(new State(this, connection));
  }
}

private sealed class State
{
  private readonly Parent _parent;

  public State(Parent parent, Connection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    _parent = parent;
    Task = ExecuteAsync(connection, cancellationToken);
  }

  private static async Task ExecuteAsync(Connection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    try { await HandleConnectionAsync(connection, cancellationToken); }
    finally { _parent.Remove(this); }
  }

  public Task Task { get; }
  // other properties as desired, e.g., RemoteAddress
}
```

You now have a collection of connections. You can either ignore the tasks in the `State` objects (as the code above is doing), which is just like fire-and-forget. Or you can `await` them all at some point. E.g.:

```
public async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  try
  {
    while (true)
    {
      var connection = await listener.AcceptAsync(cancellationToken);

      Add(new State(this, connection));
    }
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    // Wait for all connections to cancel.
    // I'm not really sure why you would *want* to do this, though.
    List<State> connections;
    lock (_mutex) { connections = _connections.ToList(); }
    await Task.WhenAll(connections.Select(x => x.Task));
  }
}
```

Then it's easy to extend the `State` object so you can do things that are sometimes useful for a server app to do, e.g.:

- List all remote addresses this server has connections to.
- Wait until a specific connection is done.
- ...

Notes:

- Use one pattern for cancellation. Passing the token will result in an `OperationCanceledException`, which is the normal cancellation pattern. The code also was formerly doing a `while (!IsCancellationRequested)`, resulting in a successful completion on cancellation, which is not the normal cancellation pattern. So I removed that so the code is no longer using two cancellation patterns.
- When working with raw sockets, in the general case, you need to be [constantly reading](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/06/using-socket-as-connected-socket.html) (even when you're writing) and [periodically writing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) (even if you have no data to send). So your `HandleConnectionAsync` should be starting an asynchronous reader and writer and then using `Task.WhenAll`.
- I removed the call to `HandleException` because (probably) whatever it does should be handled by `State.ExecuteAsync`. It's not hard to add it back in if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. Just a side question: How much of a bad idea is to expose "reading from socket" as c# 8 async enumerable? I've developed an API where connection object can return `IAsyncEnumerable<TMessage>` where TMessage is reassembled from underlying `NetworkStream`, so basically consumer of this API will read implicitly by just enumerating it with `await foreach` and I'm not sure whether this is a good idea and how to satisfy `constantly reading` rule with "async enumerable". It looks nice in code, because it just feels like enumerating a list.

Comment: Okay never mind the `constantly reading` question. I've just realized that it's the same situation with "normal" reading and writing - I have to create separate tasks for enumerating and sending.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a limit to the maximum number of allowed concurrent tasks, you should use `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
int allowedConcurrent = //..
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(allowedConcurrent);
var tasks = new List<Task>();

while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    Func<Task> func = async () =>
    {
        var connection = await listener.AcceptAsync(cancellationToken);
        await HandleConnectionAsync(connection, cancellationToken);

        semaphore.Release();
    };

    await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // Will return immediately if the number of concurrent tasks does not exceed allowed

    tasks.Add(func());
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This will accumulate the tasks into a list, then `Task.WhenAll` can wait for them all to complete.

Comment: That's nice solution, but what if each call to `AcceptAsync` allocates system resources and I want to avoid that whenever possible. It is better to assume that this is the method I don't want to be called concurrently/in parallel - I am able to accept only one connection at time.

Comment: @BART So you want to reuse the connection for multiple calls to `HandleConnectionAsync`? You could always do `var connection = await listener.AcceptAsync` before the `while` loop.

Comment: The `while loop` is the server lifecycle. When new connection is accepted then it starts some "background task" so it can handle this new connection and then `while loop` goes back to accepting new connections without awaiting anything - pausing the lifecycle. With your approach I have to invoke multiple `AcceptAsync` - up to `allowedConcurrent` which is consuming system resources even if there are currently no clients connected to the server. It also won't allow me to accept any new connections after I'm done with old connections - "fire and forget" does not have this issue

Comment: @BART I'm not completely sure what point you are trying to make. Each `connection` will be garbage collected when it leaves scope, just as it would with fire and forget.

Comment: I think the point is I have to improve my question. `AcceptAsync` already have built-in semaphore that won't allow me to accept more connections than it's allowed to - the problem is not throttling. This basically reduces the code above to keeping the list of tasks outside of the `server loop` and awaiting them when the server shuts down. In this case the list of tasks will grow indefinitely, beacuse I can have millions of clients per day connecting and disconnecting to my server - server can work for many many days. Also `AcceptAsync` is allocating system resources before returning connection

Comment: This is just regarding `AcceptAsync` - it may not return connection for hours (code is "awaiting" for hours) - until some client decides to connect to my server, but starting/calling AcceptAsync task allocates resources - that's way I don't want to "await/start" it when I don't need to - just one 'AcceptAsync' at time is enough

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

1. Don't do async void...

Then you can implement a producer/consumer pattern for this, the below pseudocode is just to guide, you need to make sure your Consumer is a Singleton in your app

```
public class Data
{
    public Uri Url { get; set; }
}

public class Producer
{
    private Consumer _consumer = new Consumer();
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var data = new Data();
        _consumer.Enqueue(data);
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    private readonly List<Data> _toDo = new List<Data>();
    private bool _stop = false;
    public Consumer()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Loop);
    }

    private async Task Loop()
    {
        while (!_stop)
        {
            Data toDo = null;
            lock (_toDo)
            {
                if (_toDo.Any())
                {
                    toDo = _toDo.First();
                    _toDo.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }

            if (toDo != null)
            {
                await DoSomething(toDo);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }

    private async Task DoSomething(Data toDo)
    {
        // YOUR ASYNC STUFF HERE
    }

    public void Enqueue(Data data)
    {
        lock (_toDo)
        {
            _toDo.Add(data);
        }
    }
}
```

So your calling method produces what you need to do the background task and the consumer performs that, that's another fire and forget.
You should consider too what happens if something goes wrong at an application level, should you store the Data in the Consumer.Enqueue() so if the app starts again can do the missing job...
Hope this helps